# Export Azure Iot Hub Devices Twins to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-blob-storage

I am trying unsuccessfully to export Azure Iot Hub devices twins to a Blob Storage, so that it can be used as a reference input in Azure Stream Analytics.
I have read and understood this documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt.
But it is in C#, and I have no idea how to make it in nodejs or javascript ... Someone who has tried something similar, or are there any other documentation or examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [azure iot node sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node) . Here's a snippet on how to export devices to Blob:

```
registry.exportDevicesToBlob(outputSasUrl, false, function (error, result) {
                       if (error) {
                           console.error('Could not create export job: ' + error.message);
                       } else {
                           console.log('--------------\r\nDevices Export Job Identifier:--------------\r\n' + result);
                           var jobId = result.jobId;
                           var interval = setInterval(function () {
                               registry.getJob(jobId, function (error, result) {
                                  if (error) {
                                      console.error('Could not get job status: ' + error.message + ' : ' + error.responseBody);
                                  } else {
                                      console.log('--------------\r\njob ' + jobId + ' status:\r\n--------------\r\n' + result);
                                      var status = result.status;
                                      if (status === "completed") {
                                          clearInterval(interval);
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                           }, 500);
                       } 
                   });
```